# Why Image::make($image) returns redirect response laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when Im trying to save image I get error that mime is not a method of request
, when I checked what i get in Image::make there was  Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse object

```
            $makeImage = Image::make($image);
            dd($makeImage); // It shows a RedirectResponse object
            $image_extention = str_replace('image/','',$makeImage->mime()); // There i get error that mime is not a method of request
```

https://prnt.sc/6Dss_yxcsmCM - screen shot of dd

Update:
after some time I refreshed the page and it works . What can be the problem ?

Comment: can you please provide the type of file you try to upload? ( extension of file )

Comment: Im geting images from server and that images are valid (jpg,jpeg)